# How to write a 3 line list in android

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

http://developer.android.com/design/media/lists_main.png

As you can see above, I would like to create the 3-line list.
I have looked everywhere but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do it.

How do I write my adapter for this kind of ListView?

Do I have to extend ListActivity, include a ListView in my .xml layout, or both?

Can somebody provide further insight into it? I'll be very grateful...

Comment: Thats done by customizing the ListView. Check [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) for making a Custom ListView.

Comment: great tutorial, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material design suggestions for lists with avatar, text and icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661305/material-design-suggestions-for-lists-with-avatar-text-and-icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an XML-Layout for your list-item (row) with three `TextView`s in a vertical `LinearLayout`. Then you need to subclass the ArrayAdapter to fill the `TextView`s. In the `getView` you fill the lines.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    }
    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textfield1);
    if (text1 != null) {
        text1.setText(contentArray.get(position).valueForField1);
    }

    // same for the other fields
    return v;
}
```