# Material design suggestions for lists with avatar, text and icon

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-drawable

I want to create `Material Designed` Android application and I try to follow all Google's suggestions about making nice layouts specially for the new `RecylcerView`. The `RecyclerView` has avatar `ImageView`, title and subtitle `TextView` and action icon `ImageView`.

What values should I put in ImageView's properites for `width` and `height` so it supports different screen sizes and densities, and what size of those drawables should I choose from the system icons pack?

[material-design-icons-1.0.1](http://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-components)

Suggestion for lists:

[image: avatar with text and icon]

**`???`** in xml code are the unknown things I don't know what to put there:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_friend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">???

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/friend_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="40dp"???
            android:layout_height="40dp"???
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_grey600_48dp"/>???

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friend_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/friend_online_imageview"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_profile_picture"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/plain_text_for_preview"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friend_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/friend_name"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/friend_online_imageview"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_profile_picture"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:text="@string/plain_text_for_preview"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/friend_online_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"???
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"???
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_messenger_grey600_18dp"/>???

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

PREVIEW:

[image: Design Preview of XML]

Comment: You already have the answer... it's there, in **dp** and **sp**. You also have **downloadable resources** on this page: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#. You're **ready to start**.

Comment: I see only 72dp for RelativeLayout height property, but then the second TextView has been cut at bottom.
http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2014/12/26/72.png
on NexusS preview device. 

I update XML with ??? tags.

Comment: i am also facing same problem... thanks for asking @fpopic

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**#1 Two line items:**

Layout `minHeight` is 72dp, `layout_height` is `wrap_content`. Icon size is 40dp (usually it's a circle bitmap). Icon has 16dp top margin and 16dp left margin, no other.

Both `TextView`s are in a vertically oriented and vertically centered `LinearLayout`. This layout has 16dp left margin and 16dp right margin. This will allow you to remove image and still have side margins intact. First line has typically `textApperance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"` and second line has `Body1`. The text layout has 16dp top and 16dp bottom **padding** (it has to be padding here because the bottom margin is not respected for children of `RelativeLayout` - and it is useful other times). Now you can put multiple lines in the second `TextView` and the whole item will expand nicely.

Don't forget to set `layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"` and `layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` on the text layout. If you have another icon (or widget) to the right add `layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_icon"`. If not use `layout_alignParentRight="true"`. This will stretch the layout to occupy all available space. Or you can use `LinearLayout`.

Put this in a list in your content area. The list does not have to have any padding at top or bottom, it will look good.

**#2 Single line items in content**

Same as number 1 with following differences: `minHeight` or `layout_height` is set to 56dp. Don't use any vertical margins or padding, just center everything vertically. Use only one line text.

Use this in a list with 8dp padding or 48dp header at the top and 8dp padding at the bottom. Otherwise it will look "cut off".

**#3 Single line items in menus**

Same as number 2 with following differences: The height is 48dp. The icon is 24dp. The icon should have the following attributes:

```
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

This will allow you to put any icon from 1dp to 40dp without upsetting the balance (you don't have to change the spacing between icon and text because it stays 40dp as in previous cases).

I use this in a navigation drawer and menus.

[image: Keylines]

**EDIT: Note**

The specs say that left and right item margins should be 24dp instead of 16dp for tablets (sw600dp). You can solve this by adding left and right item layout padding 8dp on tablets (use dynamic values).

The specs also say that the divider between items (if present) should be part of the item. You have to define the "total left margin dimen" of 72dp for phones and 80dp for tablets and use it as left margin for the divider view. Second problem is that on tablets you have an 8dp right padding. I say this: If you use `ListView`, screw the specs and set a custom divider, which will be painted between items. If you use `RecyclerView`, write a nice `ItemDecorator` which will add the divider over the item.

**EDIT 2**

`?listPreferredPaddingLeft` and `?listPreferredPaddingRight` will expand to 16dp on phones and 24dp on tablets (honoring RTL settings). You can use these values for left and right padding in list items. Then 40dp reserved for the icon, 16dp spacing and finally content.

Comment: So this would be OK with your suggestions (+ oval + itemdecorator)?
https://gist.github.com/fpopic/688c7c41379ead689596

Thanks for you big reply, I think Google should update it's default layouts in ...\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res\layout with new material layouts, but till that I will use your.

Comment: Yes that looks ok, just one thing: the right icon probably won't be the same size as 40dp. The icon centers should align. Either calculate new top margin by hand (if you know the right icon size) or wrap it in a 72dp tall frame and center vertically. Also you don't need a divider since you're using cards (but should you?). Don't count on the layouts to change, they would only be available on the newest SDK. Plus I don't remember using an item layout from SDK practically. You're better off reusing what you just wrote I think.

Comment: Yeah thanks ! 
Is there any tip for those icons (on right) about their size to fit on multiple screens, cause when I search into material-design-icons-1.0.1 for "ic_messenger_grey600_" I got http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2014/12/26/x.png
which size should I put into drawable folder with it's four dpi variants (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi) ?

Comment: For the small icons (and toolbar icons and nav drawer etc.) use 24dp. Take the `ic_messenger_grey_600_24dp.png` from `drawable-mdpi` and put it into your `drawable-mdpi` and so on.

Comment: Note: in your second edit, I believe it should be `listPreferredItemPaddingLeft` and `listPreferredItemPaddingRight`

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I trimmed the icons to the edge and fitted them into the 40dp square.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a ready-to-paste tile in [material design](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html#lists-specs) for a three-line list:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "88dp"
  android:layout_marginTop = "8dp"
  android:orientation = "vertical">

<ImageView
  android:id = "@+id/avatar"
  android:layout_width = "40dp"
  android:layout_height = "40dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom = "20dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft = "16dp"
  android:layout_marginRight = "16dp"
  android:layout_marginTop = "20dp"
  android:background = "@drawable/avatar"
  android:contentDescription = "Avatar"/>

<TextView
  android:id = "@+id/avatar_text"
  android:layout_width = "40dp"
  android:layout_height = "40dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom = "20dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft = "16dp"
  android:layout_marginRight = "16dp"
  android:layout_marginTop = "20dp"
  android:gravity = "center_vertical|center_horizontal"
  android:maxLines = "1"
  android:text = "AV"
  android:textColor = "@color/white_dark"
  android:textSize = "16sp"
  android:fontFamily="sans-serif"  
  android:textStyle = "bold"/>

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "match_parent"
  android:layout_marginBottom = "16dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd = "56dp"
  android:layout_marginStart = "72dp"
  android:layout_marginTop = "16dp"
  android:orientation = "vertical">

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  android:orientation = "horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/first_line"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd = "16dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text = "This is the title line"
    android:textColor = "@color/black_light"
    android:textSize = "16sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  android:orientation = "horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/second_line"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor = "@color/discreet_dark"
    android:textSize = "14sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    tools:text = "This is the second line"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  android:orientation = "horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/third_line"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor = "@color/discreet_dark"
    android:textSize = "14sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    tools:text = "This is the third line"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
  android:id = "@+id/minor_info"
  android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd = "true"
  android:layout_marginEnd = "16dp"
  android:layout_marginTop = "20dp"
  android:maxLines = "1"
  android:maxWidth = "40dp"
  android:text = "19 min"
  android:textColor = "@color/discreet_dark"
  android:textSize = "12sp"
  android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>

<ImageView
  android:id = "@+id/favourite"
  android:layout_width = "24dp"
  android:layout_height = "24dp"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd = "true"
  android:layout_marginBottom = "16dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft = "16dp"
  android:layout_marginRight = "16dp"
  android:contentDescription = "Favourite"
  tools:src = "@drawable/favourite_checked"/>

<View
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "1dp"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_marginStart = "72dp"
  android:background = "@color/discreet_light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```