# How can I create List with dynamically number of items with Android Studio

Tags: android, listview

I created list using example: [Material design suggestions for lists with avatar, text and icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661305/material-design-suggestions-for-lists-with-avatar-text-and-icon/27661786#27661786)

I want to have list with upcoming movies, so I need list with dynamically number of items. I dont understand and I dont know how I should do it.

There is my code for one item list:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;
    TextView textView2;
    ImageView imageView;

    public static FragmentOne newInstance() {
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
        return fragment;
    }

    public class MovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MovieDb>{
        @Override
        protected MovieDb doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            TmdbMovies movies = new TmdbApi("my_api_key").getMovies();
            MovieDb movie = movies.getMovie(5335, "en");

            return movie;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(MovieDb movieDb) {
            textView.setText(movieDb.getOriginalTitle());
            textView2.setText(movieDb.getReleaseDate());
            Glide.with(imageView).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + movieDb.getPosterPath()).into(imageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MovieTask mt = new MovieTask();
        mt.execute();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView2 = (TextView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        imageView = (ImageView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon);


        return returnView;
    }
}
```

and xml for that class

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    tools:context=".FragmentOne">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is no list. There is no adapter. You posted irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally suggest you to use Recyclerview and cardview to get this job done. You will need to create an adapter class for Recyclerview if you are not familiar with this.

Just check out this link -
https://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-android-cardview-example-tutorial

Comment: There is possibility to do what I want with my List?
I have 5 items, I want to have list with 5 items, but I could have for example 7 items and I dont want buttons for changing size of my list, it must be doing automatically. This is even possible?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible. Hope you checked the link I mentioned above. You need to create a layout having just a single cardview. Just add textviews or anything you want inside this card view. Now your recyclerview adapter will show multiple cardviews on the recyclerview layout according to the no. of data you will be storing and providing as an array.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. One more question. This will work inside fragment?

Comment: Yes it will. You will have to do a few changes and you are good to go. Just search more about recyclerview and cardview

Comment: Can I write PM to you? I have little problems during working on this recycler view.

Comment: I have this error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at kawi15.myapplication.CustomAdapter.getItemCount(CustomAdapter.java:66)


Its possibly that I do my changes not in right way and there is a little bit too much code to just copy to this comment

Comment: Ya sure! You can ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224113/discussion-between-karol-wisniewski-and-triaro).